# DISM keep giving me hr:0xc0000135 error

Tags: dism

I trying using a Win2012 R2's DISM, DeploymentWorkbench, DISM GUI and manually used powershell to manual inject the driver but all give me the same error (hr:0xc0000135 )...

For manually deployment i had used as below commends:

```
Dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:C:\Public\Apps\DSIM_GU_By_Mike\image\LitetouchPe_64.wim

DISM /Mount-Wim /wimfile:C:\Public\Apps\DSIM_GU_By_Mike\image\LitetouchPe_64.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\Public\Apps\DSIM_GU_By_Mike\mounted

Dism /Image:C:\Public\Apps\DSIM_GU_By_Mike\mounte /Add-Driver /Driver:c:C:\Dell\Drivers\TTGK8\Drivers\Win7\x64
```

Then its give me the error code : 0xc0000135

On the Dism's log:

```
2015-07-27 10:26:33, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5320 Getting the collection of providers from a local provider store type. - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection

2015-07-27 10:26:33, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5320 Getting the collection of providers from a local provider store type. - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection
2015-07-27 10:27:35, Error                 DISM   DismHostLib: Failed to create DismHostManager remote object. Checking for dismhost.exe exit code.
2015-07-27 10:27:35, Info                  DISM   DismHostLib: Found dismhost.exe exit code.
2015-07-27 10:27:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Manager: PID=5320 Failed to create Dism Image Session in host. - CDISMManager::LoadImageSession(hr:0xc0000135)
2015-07-27 10:27:35, Warning               DISM   DISM Manager: PID=5320 A problem ocurred loading the image session. Retrying...  - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession(hr:0xc0000135)
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Error                 DISM   DismHostLib: Failed to create DismHostManager remote object. Checking for dismhost.exe exit code.
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DismHostLib: Found dismhost.exe exit code.
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Manager: PID=5320 Failed to create Dism Image Session in host. - CDISMManager::LoadImageSession(hr:0xc0000135)
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Manager: PID=5320 Failed to load the image session from the temporary location: C:\Users\ckr\AppData\Local\Temp\119992EA-2242-4814-A3E7-C32210C749C8 - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession(hr:0xc0000135)
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: Could not load the image session. HRESULT=C0000135
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: Unable to start the servicing process for the image at 'C:\Public\Apps\DSIM_GU_By_Mike\mounted'. HRESULT=C0000135
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Image Session: PID=5320 Disconnecting the provider store - CDISMImageSession::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5320 Disconnecting Provider: WimManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5320 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5320 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5320 Disconnecting Provider: Compatibility Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-07-27 10:28:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5320 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

Please help.

Comment: which Widows do you use on your host and which version is the WIM? This happens when you use a 8.0 DISM to serve a 8.1 WIM for example.

Comment: I am using Win7 64Bits OS WIM. Host is win7.

Comment: and how do you use the 2012R2 one? Have you installed the 8.1 ADK? Why don't you use the Windows 7 WAIK?

Comment: i had tired again using DISM maunally injected on Win2012 R8 and it was a successful injected. For some reason i am not sure why i cant inject in a folder instead injected individually file.
My office is using Win7 OS and noone is using Win 8,1 so i only install a VB to try on the dism environment.

Comment: I had many problems with adding drivers to image with DISM and I didn't know what was the reason. I started to use `forceunsigned`. And also there was a problem when path was too long, but it was strange, because some drivers had longer paths and there was no problem. I moved all directories to the top and it helped. Also when deploying there was a problem with installing drivers, but disconnecting all USB devices helped. Now I install drivers using installer in audit mode and sysprep with `PersistAllDeviceInstalls` option in answer file and I only use DISM to add USB 3.0 drivers to boot.wim.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is resolved by using newer dism version and running it in cmd directly from WAIK folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment
 Tools\amd64\DISM>

This limitation is due to boot wims based on newer WinPE versions require newest dism.

Comment: I found the DISM that comes with the OS worked OK for mounting and dismounting, whereas a newer version was necessary for the /Add-Driver option.  I had problems mounting and dismounting with the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

Either specify "recurse" option:

`Dism /Add-Driver /Image:<FolderPath> /Driver:<DriversFolder> /Recurse`

Or single *.inf file:

`Dism /Add-Driver /Image:<FolderPath> /Driver:<DriversFolder>\<mydriver.inf>`

AND

ALLWAYS run DISM from "Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment" command prompt installed with WAIK/ADK

Answer (score 0):

First call this cmd before using dism.

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\pesetenv.cmd"
```